# Is there a library / repository / public site that contains commonly written Java Entities / Classes / Beans / Data structures? (Preferably in Java)

Tags: java, language-agnostic, code-reuse

We all reuse our code, but really, how many times did you find yourself re-writing something like this?

```
class Person{ 
    private String firtsName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date dob;
    ...
    private List<Address> addresses
```

or this

```
class Address { 
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String city;
    private String zip;
    ...
```

Wouldn't it be nice if we had a library of free, mature, well written, best practice Entity types / beans / POJOs / POCOs so we all can finally say good bye to trying to clone the world in Java / C# / (replace with your favorite language) and start writing actual code.

Is there something like that? 
Do you agree it's required?

Comment: "Bean" type objects are incredibly easy to generate.

Comment: I agree, but it's also easy to plug all the cables to your laptop in the morning and unplug them in the evening when you go home from your office, people still buy docking stations. It's also easy to press your TV's on button and people still use remote controls. we are a lazy species, and that's what make us so inventive and technological

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something like that?

I've heard of no such library.

> Do you agree it's required?

No, I don't.

There are so many possible ways that you could write domain objects like this (depending on the business requirements), that organizing such a library would be a nightmare.

Besides, this kind of object typically consists of just getters and setters, and can be written very quickly ... or even generated from a model ... so you save very little time / effort by using a library.

(By contrast, the kind of classes you find in typical reusable class libraries are much more complicated, and much more difficult to write from scratch.)

Having said that, I think there is justification for reuse of this kind of thing on a larger scale; e.g. off-the-shelf components or systems for managing customer databases, or website account details.

Comment: I have to accept this, although I don't agree it's not required, but this is subjective, and I think the answer that that it doesn't exist is good enough

Comment: @Ehrann - clearly it is subjective ... but I claim if it was required (and was practical) there would be one or more well-known examples.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking something similar to [this](http://www.skywayperspectives.org/portal/web/guest/ggfeatureddownload?gclid=CPH69P6n9ZwCFRQpawodSFnKQw).

The Skyway is an open source tool which does generate the code to your needs that helps you to save your redundant typing of **JAVA** code.

Comment: Wasn't my question, but yes, this is an interesting link

Answer (score 1):

There's [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com) which contains *tons* of Java code of different nature. The most difficult part of you asking is done there -- central, searchable repository of Java code which is used by *lots* of developers and is "common practice".

I don't know if there's some library with purpose similar to what you interested in. But if there isn't you can always write it and share it with the world via given link.